# Excel VBA ADODB query not able fetch specific date

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I am getting empty recordset when i try and execute the below query:

```
Mnbtquery = "SELECT * FROM [Sample Proposal List - 2021$A6:AB170] WHERE [PROPOSAL SUBMITTED DATE]= #31/1/2021#"
```

Comment: Try formatting your date as yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Is the data in you column a pure date or are they date+time? (or is it a string that looks like a date?).  Try `WHERE int([PROPOSAL SUBMITTED DATE])`. That said: I would *always* use ADODB.Commands and ADODB.Parameters when I have a Parameter in a query, especially when it comes to dates. Takes a little bit more time to write the code but saves you lots of headaches because you don't need to take care about date formats or quotes or what database system is on the back end

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas. I fixed it by changing the format of date column in the sheet to format without any dots(eg: 31.1.2021 to 31-1-2021). Its funny that was the issue.

Comment: This is exactly why I always advocate to use ADODB.Parameter. With that you don't have such problems because there a date is a date, no matter how it is displayed

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi venom181. Maybe try formatting the value like this: WHERE [PROPOSAL SUBMITTED DATE]=#" and Format(CDate(your criteria or range), "MM/DD/YYYY")